# jQuery.grep usage for finding keywords and phrases

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

Need help with finding keywords and phrases from a textarea using jQuery.grep so that it is not an exact match but *contains* certain keyword(s) and/or phrase(s) in an array.

Right now this only works if the textarea is the **exact** word or phrase matching the array:

```
function isSpam(array, name){
    return $.grep(array, function(i) {
        return i == name;
    }).length > 0;
}
```

**Link: http://jsfiddle.net/2ejC5/**

But does not work if there is a match **and** some other text. Not sure how the syntax should be to make it work matching *any* keywords and phrases from the array.

Also, is there an alternate way to do this with indexOf?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function isSpam(array, name){
    return $.grep(array, function(i) {
        return name.indexOf(i) >= 0;
    }).length > 0;
}
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/barmar/2ejC5/1/)